# gdal_translate (python) seems to fail with (arbitrarily?) different window

Tags: python, gdal, sentinel-2, gdal-translate, gdal-python-binding

I'm trying to take a satellite image tile (Sentinel 2, product 2A) and crop it to a smaller window using lat lon coords. I've created a tiff image combining all of the different Sentinel 2 bands using this code: https://github.com/dairejpwalsh/Sentinel-Scripts

If I crop the image like so:

```
DUMP_FILE_NAME = ...
TIF_FILE_PATH = ...

window = (-88.85120523926013,44.28567970079606, -88.26144083496325, 43.9340763284468 )
gdal.UseExceptions()
gdal.Translate(DUMP_FILE_NAME, TIF_FILE_PATH, projWin = window, projWinSRS="EPSG:4326")
```

It successfully creates the new tif file and I can display the RGB channels properly:
[image]

However, as you can see, the lat lon coordinates I've provided go out of the bounds of the original image (on the top). So naturally I would like to crop the latitude even more. So I try these bounds:

```
DUMP_FILE_NAME = ...
TIF_FILE_PATH = ...

window = (-88.85120523926013,44.22567970079606, -88.26144083496325, 43.9340763284468 )
gdal.UseExceptions()
gdal.Translate(DUMP_FILE_NAME, TIF_FILE_PATH, projWin = window, projWinSRS="EPSG:4326")
```

All I've changed is the top left corner latitude value to `44.22...` instead of `44.28...`

Now, when I try to display the image it is entirely black, and I've confirmed that the values are all 0 (in all bands).
[image]

What could possibly be causing this issue?

As shown above, I am trying to raise exceptions for GDAL, but nothing is being thrown.

Is it possible something is wrong with my source TIF file?

Note that I've tried various changes to the window, and I can't seem to find a pattern of when it works and when it doesn't.

Here is the link to the original (post merging of bands) TIF image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S0ebdtDACbfOmgxshv9o2f20eiU3LsLs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The window looks right and of course it should work with any valid input, but have you tested other values than `44.28567970079606`? Or with less decimals?

Comment: I just updated my q to address that actually - I've tried other values and I can't figure out the pattern that causes it to sometimes work and sometimes not. Less decimals still shows a black image. Generally I believe making the image smaller (particularly in the y axis) is causing the issue.

Comment: Could you have a test by converting the whole source file into tiled TIFF ( -co TILED=YES option in gdal_translate) and then making a new trial with the window that fails now?

Comment: Converting the whole source file into a tiled TIFF, and then subsuquently translating the tiled TIFF file results in a black image for both lat lon coords (including the one that previously worked).

Comment: The link to the original TIF image is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S0ebdtDACbfOmgxshv9o2f20eiU3LsLs/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a test with your image with GDAL 3.6.0dev on Windows. I used this command

```
gdal_translate -f GTiff -projwin -88.85120523926013 44.22567970079606 -88.26144083496325 43.9340763284468 -projwin_srs EPSG:4326 merged.tif merged2.tif
```

The result looks good in QGIS (the colors are a bit odd because this is a multi-band  image with 16 bands and UInt16 as a datatype and QGIS rendering defaults may not be optimal).

[image]

It is very hard to say why just that window makes an all black result for you. I can only suggest to use other GDAL versions.

Comment: Thanks. It seems as if something is wrong with the python bindings. I opened a subprocess and called gdal_translate directly and it worked perfectly.